# Relay-like digital potentiometer?

Tags: relay, h-bridge, digital-potentiometer

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to control an AC motor with their microcontroller and I've found a good relay module to use, however, I still want to be able to control the voltage via the microcontroller... Is there anything out there equivalent to how a relay is an AC switch controlled by a DC signal but for digital potentiometers?

Comment: wait you speak of an AC motor then an H bridge then polarity... is that AC or DC?

Comment: AC motor, but being controlled via DC components... sorta how a relay is an AC switch, controlled via DC signals...

Comment: Is there some compelling reason why you can't use the H bridge in conjunction with pulsewidth modulation to get rotation direction and speed control?

Comment: No, I just realized my error on the h-bridge configuration... though I am still interested in the idea of using a DC signal from a microcontroller to control an AC digital potentiometer...

Comment: Generally these things are called "electronic speed controllers", but usually only work for DC or brushless DC motors.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial units available called Variable Frequency Drives (VFD).  These vary the frequency supplied to AC induction motors to allow the speed to varied.  They also control the voltage sent to the motor - as the frequency is brought below the design frequency for the motor, the voltage must be also reduced so that the magnetic circuits inside the motor don't saturate.  This is usually okay because in most systems, the torque that the motor is required to supply drops as the speed drops.

You can certainly build your own version but you need to be aware that you are dealing with lethal voltage and power levels.  But pounding the string "diy vfd drive" into Google brings up many pages that describe what is involved.

Comment: That's very interesting and I'm definitely going to look into it, but I'm still curious if there's anything like an AC digital potentiometer that is controlled via DC signals (like relays)... do you know of anything like that?

Comment: @JacobEdward - a potentiometer, digital or not, is the wrong way to control a motor's speed. An AC motor's speed is controlled by the AC frequency, not the voltage; reducing the voltage will only make it stall. A DC motor **can** be controlled by a series potentiometer, but the pot will get hot as it is dissipating power; PWM control is mucg more efficient and can easily be done by most microcontrollers.